# No matching version found for @storybook/react-native@^5.0.6

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, storybook

Any possible to solutions to fix the following error on running the command

`npx -p @storybook/cli sb init -f`

```
 • Preparing to install dependencies. ✓

npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @storybook/react-native@^5.0.6
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'MySampleApp'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/atif/.npm/_logs/2019-04-04T10_51_13_555Z-debug.log

 • Installing dependencies. ✖
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `@storybook/react-native@^^5.0.6`, (only 5.0.0 and 5.1.0).

Maybe version 5.0.6 was removed or never created.

My recommend is install another version `@storybook/react-native`, if `@storybook/react-native` require by other package, create an issue to that author of that module.